# Inner Join and Right Join same query

Tags: mysql, innodb, join

I'm using MySQL and InnoDB,
I have a table `reserver` with 2 columns : `idReservation` and `idChambre`
I have a table `reservation` and a table `chambre`

Now I want my query to return every "chambre.id" who is not between my dateDebut and dateFin.

Below is my actual query :

```
SELECT cre.id
FROM   reserver AS rer
       INNER JOIN reservation AS ron
         ON rer.idReservation = ron.id
       RIGHT JOIN chambre AS cre
         ON rer.idChambre = cre.id
WHERE (ron.dateFin < ?
    OR ron.dateDebut > ?
    OR (ron.dateFin = NULL AND ron.dateDebut = NULL))
```

My problem is that my return value only contains chambre when the id of the chambre is already in reserver.

My second problem is that "RIGHT JOIN" add every chambre to my query, but what I want is only chambre as : "ron.dateFin < ? OR ron.dateDebut > ?" or chambre who are not already on linked to reserver.

EDIT : here's some sample rows :

### reserver :

```
id |idReservation | idChambre
---+--------------+----------
0  | 1            | 1
```

### chambre :

```
id | idCategorie
---+------------
1  | 1
2  | 2
```

### reservation :

```
id | date       | dateDebut  | dateFin
---+------------+------------+---------
1  | 03/04/2015 | 01/04/2015 | 06/04/2015
2  | 05/04/2015 | 08/04/2015 | 12/04/2015
```

I want my query to return id 1 and 2 for chambre but all I get actually is 1

P.S : Sorry, english is not my native language but stackexchange is such an amazing website.

Comment: Your query will return all `chambre.id`. What exactly do you want? It's better if you provide sample rows and what happens (vs. what you want).

Comment: Thanks you for taking time to answer this, what I want is all chambre.id but all I get is id which are already in reserver. I'll edit my first comment with sample rows

Comment: This returns `1` and `2` [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31823/1)

Comment: Yeah, I tested as well: [SQL-fiddle-2 (same as @Martin's)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e74e/1)

Comment: So it's seems that my problem is with my condition, do you have any idea how to get chambre.id if data from other column of the row are NULL ?
Here's my code :
AND (ron.dateFin < ?
OR ron.dateDebut > ?
OR (ron.dateFin = NULL AND ron.dateDebut = NULL))

Comment: Your condition (the condition in the question) is fine (if you want what you say you want). But the sample you provided is not the same as your data. Or your `SELECT` list is different to what you show us. If your condition was different, edit the question and add it. No need to waste other people's time with something you don't actually use.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not familiar with asking question, I'm on my own most of the time. My SELECT is actually the same as shown in my first message, I'm just updating it with the condition.

Comment: You select may be the same but the query isn't. My bet is that you have a `WHERE` clause you did not show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a column from a table on the "wrong"<sup>*</sup> side of an `OUTER` join, the join usually  becomes equivalent to an `INNER` join.

<sup>* *"wrong": right side of a `LEFT` join and left side of a `RIGHT` join.*</sup>

So, the solution is usually to move the condition from the `WHERE` to the `ON` of the outer join. Like this:

```
SELECT cre.id,
       rer.idChambre                 -- to actually see NULL
                                     -- where there is no match
FROM   reserver AS rer
       INNER JOIN reservation AS ron
         ON rer.idReservation = ron.id
       RIGHT JOIN chambre AS cre
         ON rer.idChambre = cre.id
         AND (ron.dateFin < ?
             OR ron.dateDebut > ?
             OR (ron.dateFin IS NULL AND ron.dateDebut IS NULL)) ;
```

- Another issue is the `= NULL` that have to be converted to `IS NULL`. Nulls are tricky and are not equal to anything, not even to themselves.

---

It seems it wass not very clear what exactly you wanted. Your issue - as far as I can understand from the question and the following comments - is that you want:

*Find all rooms (chambres) that are not reserved for the specific period (4 April 2015 to 4 May 2015)?*

Then your query could be rewritten like this:

```
SELECT cre.id
FROM   chambre AS cre
       LEFT JOIN 
                 reserver AS rer
                 INNER JOIN reservation AS ron
                 ON rer.idReservation = ron.id
                 AND (ron.dateFin > '2015-04-04 00:00:00'
                    AND ron.dateDebut < '2015-05-04 00:00:00')
       ON rer.idChambre = cre.id
WHERE 
    rer.idReservation IS NULL ;
```

See the [SQLfiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3edbc/19) for various other ways to write it (Please avoid, `RIGHT` joins as much as you can. They confuse many developers who are used to work with `LEFT` outer joins only.

Comment: You just saved me lot of times, thanks you so much.

Comment: Hello my friend, I'm getting a problem with your SQL, this fiddle explain it : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3edbc/5. As you can see, my request return 1 and 2 but it should only return 2 because the chambre 1 is between dateDebut and dateFin. (I don't know if I should open a new thread ?).

Comment: The query return both 1 and 2 because they are in `chambre` and because of the RIGHT join (no mater if they are in the other tables). That's what you wanted. It also returns NULL for both, because no row matches your condition `(ron.dateFin < '2015-04-04 00:00:00' OR ron.dateDebut > '2015-05-04 00:00:00')` I don't see any "between" in the code.

Comment: Ok so what I want is that when there's already chambre.id in reserver, then "right join" won't add this chambre.id. I Have no idea how to do that, any hint ?

Comment: Forget about right and left joins and edit your question adding the wanted output.

Comment: I did it, I'm not sure if I'm clear enough but if you need more information just tell me ! Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a wanted output. (add one, formatted like the 3 tables you have)

Comment: Do you want to find all rooms (chambres) that are not reserved for the specific period (4 April to 5 April)?

Comment: YOU GOT IT. I spent 5 minutes to try to figure out how to ask this correctly and you come up with better than me. So now that we have our question, what the answer would looks like ? I was wondering about doing this in PHP because SQL is not really my thing as you can see.

Comment: Edited the answer. (and the dates, 4-April to 4-May, **not 5-April**)

Comment: You are amazing, thanks buddy ! I wish I could upvote you

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you use parentheses to make sure:

```
FROM ( a JOIN b ) RIGHT JOIN c
```

or

```
FROM a JOIN ( b RIGHT JOIN c )
```

depending on which is more correct.

Comment: Parentheses are not needed unless there are `CROSS` joins, only to help developers understand the code. The logical order of joining is determined by the placement of the `ON` clauses.